# How to know if I get a good Weka result

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I have used Weka to train my data set, but I don't know if I got a good result then.
Can someone gives me some ideas?
This is my result:

```
=== Stratified cross-validation ===
=== Summary ===

Correctly Classified Instances        2823               97.9188 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances        60                2.0812 %
Kappa statistic                          0     
Mean absolute error                      0.0208
Root mean squared error                  0.1443
Relative absolute error                 50.6234 %
Root relative squared error            101.0568 %
Coverage of cases (0.95 level)          97.9188 %
Mean rel. region size (0.95 level)      50      %
Total Number of Instances             2883     
Ignored Class Unknown Instances                119     

=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

                 TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
                 0.000    0.000    0.000      0.000    0.000      0.000    0.500     0.020     0
                 1.000    1.000    0.979      1.000    0.989      0.000    0.500     0.940     1
Weighted Avg.    0.979    0.979    0.959      0.979    0.969      0.000    0.500     0.921     

=== Confusion Matrix ===

    a    b   <-- classified as
    0   60 |    a = 0
    0 2823 |    b = 1
```

Comment: So what's your definition of `good`?

Comment: Usually the first place worth a look is the relative accuracy, here `97.9188%` on the upper right of the output. That's "good", but your `ROC area` (don't ask)  is 0.5, essentially random. Everything was classified as "b", even 60  "a"s. There are other issues. You probably passed in an uninteresting dataset or misconfigured your classification attempt.

Answer (score -1):

2 classes was used, tagged with b classes all instances correctly classified, so Correctly Classified Instances rate = 2823/(2823+60) = 97.9188% and class 1 TP value is 1, but never tagged with a classes instances correctly classified so Incorrectly Classified Instances rate = 60/(2823+60) = 2.0812% and class 0 TP value is 0